# lame-3.100.tar.gz has no lame.exe?

Tags: lame

guys!I have downloaded lame-3.100.tar.gz from the site of lame,and I want to convert one song which format is ape to mp3 by Foobar2000.But there's no lame.exe when I have unarchivered the document.Does anybody know solutions?

Comment: please provide the download link.

Comment: @LeiYang Here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/

Comment: @Oniros can you download this: http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php

Comment: @LeiYang There are *many* websites online where you can download lame.exe. Why use "rarewares.org" specifically?

Comment: @AnnanFay can you give one example?

Comment: @LeiYang [1](https://www.free-codecs.com/download/lame_encoder.htm), [2](https://www.download3k.com/Install-LAME-MP3-Encoder.html), are a couple I found on google. It's quite possible rarewares.org is the original source, or a better source. It seems like a valid reason for using rarewares.org should be posted as a complete answer and not just a comment.

Comment: @AnnanFay i had done that, but got two downvotes(reason saying such question should be closed instead of answered), and soon deleted.